# TCP Asynchronous socket slow on receiving server?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, tcp

So my problem is the my server cannot receive all the data the client is sending , which is causing virtually no packets to be getting received at all on server side.

Basically the problem is I need to quite heavily sleep the CLientLoop , in order for the sent data to be received. as in Thread.Sleep(1000)

(This is been tested locally)

My server code is here :

```
    public void RecieveAsync()
    {
        socket.BeginReceive(lenBuffer, 0, lenBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,recieveCallBack, null);
    }

    private void recieveCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

            int rec = socket.EndReceive(ar);
            if (rec == 0)
            {
                if (Disconnected != null)
                {
                    Disconnected(this);
                    return;
                }

                if (rec != 4)
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
            }
        /

        buffer = new ReceiveBuffer(BitConverter.ToInt32(lenBuffer, 0));
```

Also my buffer class for those interested (Might help)

\    public struct ReceiveBuffer
    {
        public const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
        public byte[] Buffer;
        public int ToReceive;
        public MemoryStream BufStream;

```
    public ReceiveBuffer(int toRec)
    {
        Buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        ToReceive = toRec;
        BufStream = new MemoryStream(toRec);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Buffer = null;
        ToReceive = 0;
        Close();
        if (BufStream != null) BufStream.Dispose();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        if (BufStream != null && BufStream.CanWrite)
        {
            BufStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

So my client is sending the data in this method

```
    public void Send(byte[] data, int index, int length)
    {
        //add data as state
        socket.BeginSend(BitConverter.GetBytes(length), 0, 4, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(sendCallback), data);
        socket.BeginSend(data, index, length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(sendCallback), null);
    }
```

Where the information being sent is here

```
    public void ClientLoop()
    {


        try{

        Console.WriteLine("In Client loop");

            client.DataRecieved +=new Client.DataRecievedEventHandler(Client_DataRecieved);

        while (true)
        {

            byte[] playerData = PreparePlayerData();

            client.Send(playerData, 0, playerData.Length);

            //client.RecieveAsync();

            Thread.Sleep(10);

        }


                   }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

with

```
    public byte[] PreparePlayerData()
    {


        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(new MemoryStream());
        bw.Write((int)Commands.Text);


        string data = "";

        string Position = Math.Round(MultiplayerScreen.localPlayer.Position.X, 2).ToString() + "|" + Math.Round(MultiplayerScreen.localPlayer.Position.Y, 2).ToString();
        string effects = (MultiplayerScreen.localPlayer.Effects == Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteEffects.None) ? "0" : "1";
        string animaton = (MultiplayerScreen.localPlayer.Animation.MoveState).ToString();
        string frame = MultiplayerScreen.localPlayer.Animation.XFrame.ToString();


        data = "P|" + Position + "|" + effects + "|" + animaton + "|" + frame;

        bw.Write(data);

        bw.Close();

        byte[] toSend = ((MemoryStream)bw.BaseStream).ToArray();

        bw.BaseStream.Dispose();


        return toSend;

    }
```

Also this is the method where the server processes the data received

```
    void Client_DataRecieved(Client sender, ReceiveBuffer e)
    {

        BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(e.BufStream);

        Commands header = (Commands)r.ReadInt32();

        string s = r.ReadString();

        Console.WriteLine("Client has received " + s);

        switch (header)
        {
            case Commands.Player:
                {

                    HandlePlayerData(s);

                    Console.WriteLine("The player data has been updated");

                }
                break;
            case Commands.Text:
                {
                    if (s.StartsWith("clientAccepted"))
                    {
                        connectedPlayer.isOnline = true;
                    }
                    if (s.StartsWith("P|"))
                    {
                        s = s.Remove(0, 2);
                        HandlePlayerData(s);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

        socket.BeginReceive(buffer.Buffer, 0, buffer.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, receivePacketCallback, null);

    }

    void receivePacketCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        int rec = socket.EndReceive(ar);

        if (rec <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        buffer.BufStream.Write(buffer.Buffer, 0, rec);

        buffer.ToReceive -= rec;

        if (buffer.ToReceive > 0)
        {
            Array.Clear(buffer.Buffer, 0, buffer.Buffer.Length);

            socket.BeginReceive(buffer.Buffer, 0, buffer.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, receivePacketCallback, null);

            return;

        }

        if (DataRecieved != null)
        {
            buffer.BufStream.Position = 0;
            DataRecieved(this, buffer);
        }

        buffer.Dispose();

    }
```

Comment: 'I need to quite heavily sleep the CLientLoop , in order for the sent data to be recieved' - whatever the reason is for this, (bad protocol, no protocol or whatever), it is the wrong approach, by far.

Comment: Can you reduce your code to a *minimal* example? At the moment, there's just too much code and it's not clear what you are doing overall.